# How can I create and display a UISlider programmatically in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I found the code below in the Apple documentation and added it to my `viewDidLoad` method but the slider doesn't appear when I run the code.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
slider.continuous = YES;
slider.value = 25.0;
```

Comment: Those numbers should all be floats.

Comment: Your question is very useful :)

Comment: Here is the [swift version] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530286/how-to-customize-uislider-value-in-swift) of this question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add the slider into your view hierarchy. Add `[self.view addSubview:slider];` and it should work.

Answer (score 23):

#### Try this Code:

**Create a new slider**

```
-(IBAction)mySlider
{ 
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.value = 25.0;
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
}
```

---

**Slider Actions**

```
-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;
    float value = slider.value;
    //-- Do further actions
}
```

Comment: To access the slider value, use the UISlider property called "value". Please edit your answer. It crashes as written.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the view via [self.view addSubview:slider]
AS PREVIOUS MENTIONED -  is essential.

wasn't visible FOR ME at :
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);

You should probably drop it down a bit and maybe get it off the left margin.

perhaps?
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 10.0, 200.0, 10.0);

For ios 6 and later you should really add this to view did load as well
(so you can see it - even if you lowered the frame)

```
  if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
  {
      self.edgesForExtendedLayout=NO;
  }
```