# How to customize UISlider Value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I create `UISlider` Programmatically. I try to customise `UISlider` value as 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 6.0, ... Anybody give me the solution

```
sliderDemo = UISlider(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,20))
    var numberOfSteps : NSInteger = numbers.count - 1
    sliderDemo.minimumValue = 6.5
    sliderDemo.maximumValue = 4.1
    sliderDemo.continuous = true
    sliderDemo.value = 4.0
    sliderDemo.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(sliderDemo)

func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider!)
{
    println("number:\(sender.value)")
}
```

Comment: @NimitParekh why he need to have custom controller ?

Comment: @Bala can you please tell us about the issue you are facing?

Comment: You want that your slider does not have 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9 ?

Comment: @OmerWaqasKhan Because i want to show Human height in slider so i want to customize UISlider Value ... if slider attempt 4.11 the next value must be 5.0 ... my minimum value is 4.9 and max value is 6.11 ...

Comment: You need to write logic for this in sliderValueDidChange

Comment: Read this post, it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219056/uislider-that-snaps-to-a-fixed-number-of-steps-like-text-size-in-the-ios-7-sett/8219848#8219848

Answer (score 7):

I just create an example of a custom slider for you, in this case I am creating and adding it myself to the form but you can easily adapt to use the one from storyboard, all you need to do is to add your values to the numbers array, the result will be in the variable number in the valueChanged function, you can use observer, notifications or protocol to retrieve the value as it change, or simply call a function from there.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var slider:UISlider?
    // These number values represent each slider position
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] //Add your values here
    var oldIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slider = UISlider(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.view.addSubview(slider!)

        // slider values go from 0 to the number of values in your numbers array
        var numberOfSteps = Float(numbers.count - 1)
        slider!.maximumValue = numberOfSteps;
        slider!.minimumValue = 0;

        // As the slider moves it will continously call the -valueChanged:
        slider!.continuous = true; // false makes it call only once you let go
        slider!.addTarget(self, action: "valueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    }
    func valueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        // round the slider position to the nearest index of the numbers array
        var index = (Int)(slider!.value + 0.5);
        slider?.setValue(Float(index), animated: false)
        var number = numbers[index]; // <-- This numeric value you want
        if oldIndex != index{
            println("sliderIndex:\(index)")
            println("number: \(number)")
            oldIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you!

Comment: Thanks for reply ... i use ur code its very helpful for me ... i replace the numbers array value by 'var numbers = [4.9, 4.10, 4.12, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 5.12, 5.11, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 6.12, 6.11]' its partially give output ... The problem is the index is take from 5, so the first value i get is 5.2 ... Coul'd u help me

Comment: Sorry I am confuse, I just run with the array you posted and it goes one by one without problem, maybe I am not understanding well what you want to archive.

Comment: I am sure I am able to help you, if I understand what is that you need. Maybe you are changing the minimumValue and maximumValue, if you are don't do that, just change the array and don't read the index but the varible number

Comment: Helped me a lot, thanks, Swift3 fix : `slider!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged), for: .valueChanged)`

Comment: Bala, you are getting your first value showing as 5 because you are still setting your minimum at 4.1 in the slider value IB property. Change it to 0 (zero) so that it can read from the first element in the array, which passes the 4.1 value